# Sort strings by splitted words

Tags: python, string, file, sorting

The program to handle log files with a text like below.
Please help to realize how to print a list of components (after date and time), arranging them by the importance of messages in the logs (first word).

For example, component A should be in the list before the component B, if it has more messages with most important level.

```
   ERROR - 2015 Dec 28 14:48:30 - unfulminating_deacon - 55 - airtightly unintelligently appropriable arlen
   INFO - 2015 Dec 28 02:02:56 - mangiest_ima - 144 - overrealistically decadently unfierce edris
   CRITICAL - 2015 Dec 27 20:04:02 - unanticipated_konnor - 44 - amusively sensationally turbanlike rico
   INFO - 2015 Dec 28 08:12:06 - unfulminating_deacon - 123 - eruptively nonmodally sebacic shavonda
   CRITICAL - 2015 Dec 28 08:04:27 - unanticipated_konnor - 1213 - unchastely priorly monophyletic cullen
   ERROR - 2015 Dec 28 07:39:36 - furnacelike_marlene - 1414 - healthfully flinchingly unbombastic slyvia
   DEBUG - 2015 Dec 27 16:44:47 - mangiest_ima - 144 - questingly substitutionally uncompensative jen
   ERROR - 2015 Dec 26 17:49:26 - furnacelike_marlene - 1414 - healthfully flinchingly unbombastic slyvia

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
unanticipated_konnor 
furnacelike_marlene 
unfulminating_deacon 
mangiest_ima
```

I have made some code which counts frequency of messages for components, but I'm not sure that it can help:

```
from collections import Counter
file = open('C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\tasks\\logs\\1.txt', "r+")
warnList = []
for line in file:
    warnList.append(line.split(' - ')[2])
res1 = dict(Counter(warnList))
print "Frequency of messages for components: {} \n".format(res1)
file.close()
```

Every suggestion will be highly appreciated,

Hope for your help or advice,

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure that i understood your question correctly, but if you want to sort your log file by importance, try this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import re
import operator
import collections
import pprint as pp

importance = {
    'CRITICAL': 0,
    'ERROR': 100,
    'INFO': 200,
    'DEBUG': 300
}

with open('log.log', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines() 

parsed = collections.OrderedDict()

for line in data:
    cols = re.split(r'\s+\-\s+', line)
    parsed[line] = importance[cols[0]]

for k,v in sorted(parsed.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
    print(k)
```

Output:

```
CRITICAL - 2015 Dec 27 20:04:02 - unanticipated_konnor - 44 - amusively sensationally turbanlike rico
CRITICAL - 2015 Dec 28 08:04:27 - unanticipated_konnor - 1213 - unchastely priorly monophyletic cullen
ERROR - 2015 Dec 28 14:48:30 - unfulminating_deacon - 55 - airtightly unintelligently appropriable arlen
ERROR - 2015 Dec 28 07:39:36 - furnacelike_marlene - 1414 - healthfully flinchingly unbombastic slyvia
ERROR - 2015 Dec 26 17:49:26 - furnacelike_marlene - 1414 - healthfully flinchingly unbombastic slyvia
INFO - 2015 Dec 28 02:02:56 - mangiest_ima - 144 - overrealistically decadently unfierce edris
INFO - 2015 Dec 28 08:12:06 - unfulminating_deacon - 123 - eruptively nonmodally sebacic shavonda
DEBUG - 2015 Dec 27 16:44:47 - mangiest_ima - 144 - questingly substitutionally uncompensative jen
```

If it's not what you wanted please clarify what do you need.

If you need only the third column:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import re
import operator
import collections
import pprint as pp

importance = {
    'CRITICAL': 0,
    'ERROR': 100,
    'INFO': 200,
    'DEBUG': 300
}

with open('log.log', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines() 

parsed = collections.OrderedDict()

for line in data:
    cols = re.split(r'\s+\-\s+', line)
    parsed[cols[2]] = importance[cols[0]]

for k,v in sorted(parsed.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
    print(k)
```

Output:

```
unanticipated_konnor
furnacelike_marlene
unfulminating_deacon
mangiest_ima
```

Comment: It is exactly what I need. Thank you very much for your help!